# fadein function to specific elements of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html-lists

I have a video slider that works by clicking a thumbnail and then playing the video. The problem is I'm trying to create a function so that the video fades in instead of just showing up. I can do that normally, but since the thumbnails/videos are in list form, I'm confused as how to set it up. 
The part in the body is like this

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="bigPic">
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
                <video alt="" height="786" width="1024" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
            </div>


  <div class="buttons">
    <div id="content">
        <ul class='thumbs'>
                <li rel='1'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo1();"/></li>
                <li rel='2'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo2();"/></li>
                <li rel='3'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo3();"/></li>
                <li rel='4'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo4();"/></li>
                <li rel='5'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo5();"/></li>
                <li rel='6'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" onClick="javascript:playVideo6();"/></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

The function for the play video (the first one, at least) is

```
function playVideo1() {
       var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.src = 'images/clip2.mp4'
           myVideo.load();
           myVideo.play();
           myVideo.easeIn();   
       }
```

Comment: What do you mean I can do that normally can you please explain

Comment: You should probably include the code for the playVideo() functions aswell ?

Comment: @Samad sorry, normally (I mean with images instead of videos) I'm able to apply a function that makes them transition from one to the other by fading. With the videos I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's how I would do it!

Not sure what your doing, but I would just use one video element, and change that as needed. Unless you're playing more than one video at the time, you don't really need a seperate element for each video.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bigPic">
        <video id="myVid" alt="" height="240" width="360" style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-16px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <div id="content">
            <ul class='thumbs'>
                <li rel='1'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
                <li rel='2'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
                <li rel='3'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
                <li rel='4'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
                <li rel='5'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
                <li rel='6'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="281" height="128" /></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd also drop the onclick functions and do that with jQuery instead, like so:

```
$('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {....});
```

Now all you need is a function to fade the video element and replace the source, I'd go for something dynamic, preferably naming the video's `video1.mp4`, `video2.mp4` etc. and use the `li` elements index to select the video, but you could also place the links for the video's in an array, and still use the index, something like:

```
var numb = $(this).index(),
    videos = ['images/clip0.mp4', 'images/clip1.mp4', 'images/clip2.mp4'],
    thisVideo = videos[numb];
```

All in all it would look something like :

```
$('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
    var numb = $(this).index(),
        videos = ['images/clip0.mp4', 'images/clip1.mp4', 'images/clip2.mp4'],
        myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
    $(myVideo).animate({opacity : 0}, 1500, function() {
        myVideo.src = videos[numb];
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
        $(myVideo).animate({opacity : 1}, 1500);
    });
});
```

​I added an ID to the video element, as it's faster and easier than searching the DOM for tagNames.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DnT54/1/) to show how it works, could still need a little help, but atleast a demo of some sorts!
​

Comment: would the play function be able to work on iPad? That's what it's for, but if not I can adapt the one I have. Thanks either way, this helps alot!

Comment: Both jQuery and the video element should work on iPad. I assume that `play()` is what you are reffering to, and as far as I know that works just fine.

Comment: for some reason it's not working. when the thumbs are clicked on, there it no change. What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

You could place a solid div over top of the video, and fade it out.  The audio will be full volume from the start -- probably will disrupt the effect.

Comment: okay, but then I would have to reset that div each time I click a different thumb. It's worth a shot, and the video can be delayed to start later so the audio doesn't mess it up....